# Infinite producer using BlockingCollection

Tags: c#, producer-consumer, tpl-dataflow

Please have a review of this Code chunk and let me know whether it is a good way for infinite Producer?

```
UniqueStrings = new BlockingCollection<string>(10);
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    UniqueStrings.Add(GetNextUniqueStringNumber("RCH04"));
                }
                catch (OperationCanceledException e)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("ERROR_UNIQUE_STRING_ADD: {0}", e.Message);
                }
            }
        });
```

Where `GetNextUniqueStringNumber("RCH04")` gives unique string every time. In other words, I want Unique string readily available every time Consumer takes from it.

**EDIT:**

```
public void Process()
    {
        while (!ProcessedCollection.IsCompleted)
        {
            try
            {
                string stringId = UniqueStrings.Take();
                Console.WriteLine("Unique String: {0}", stringId);
                // TODO - Use this String Id for further processing
            }
            catch (OperationCanceledException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("DATABASE_MANAGER: Operation Canceled. " + e.Message);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Could you add a usage example?

Comment: @t3chb0t Please see updated code. Thanks

Comment: I may be showing my ignorance here, but why not just call `GetNextUniqueStringNumber` from within `Process`? It's not clear to me what benefit you are getting from using the `BlockingCollection`.

Comment: Because `GetNextUniqueStringNumber` is based on Database calls. So, instead calling it when needed I kept certain unique strings readily available in Collection. You are confused because I cannot paste whole code and then ask for suggestion. I just want to know whether it is good to have infinite loop to keep producing unique strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Looks Good To Me.

I was initially confused by this code, so I would want to rename the collection from `UniqueStrings` to something like `UniqueStringBuffer`, to make the purpose clear. To me, "buffer" says "I will use this object to hold data temporarily, because the data is consumed at a different rate than it is produced" - which is exactly what you have here.

If you want to take the next step in that direction... I would note that a `BlockingCollection` can be used for many things, but the only method that should be called on your instance is `Take`. For that reason, you may want to encapsulate this code inside of a class, with `Take` (or perhaps something more explicit like `GetNext`) as its only public method. That would serve the dual purpose of preventing misuse and, again, making the purpose clear. Whether or not you want to go that far is up to you.

Comment: Yes that's correct. Renaming clarifies the purpose. Thanks